# unable to make network call after accessing contacts in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am having a very strange situation here.In my app i am trying to access the contacts of user's phone when user granted the permission then i am trying to make a network call to server.My code works fine in accessing contacts then after making network call delegate method is never called.

**Code**

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
    {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            // First time access has been granted, add the contact
            NSLog(@"access contact");
            [self sample];//Here is the function i call for making network request.
        });
    }
    else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
    {
        // The user has previously given access, add the contact
        NSLog(@"previous access");
    }
    else
    {
        // The user has previously denied access
        // Send an alert telling user to change privacy setting in settings app
        NSLog(@"send alert");
    }
```

**function to make network request**

```
-(void)sample
{
    NSLog(@"sample func called");
    // Create the request.
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.42/login"]];

    // Specify that it will be a POST request
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    // This is how we set header fields
    [request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // Convert your data and set your request's HTTPBody property
    NSString *stringData = @"some data";
    NSData *requestBodyData = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;

    // Create url connection and fire request
    sampleConn= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


}
```

**Delegate methods**

```
 //delegate methods of NSURLCONNECTION
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {
        NSLog(@"response recieved");

    }
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
    {

        if([connection isEqual:sampleConn])
        {
            NSLog(@"this is sample");

        }
    }
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
    {
        NSLog(@"fail to load");

    }
    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {



    }
```

When i call `[self sample];` then function is called but the delegate method is never called & i don't get response for that.But if i call this function from anywhere else in the code then it works fine.

Comment: where are your delegate methods?

Comment: It's in my code.I didn't mention them here

Comment: use breakpoints and check if the url connection is fired or not

Comment: Also post your delegate methods here,so that if there is something wrong in them,we could know.

Comment: URL is fired but delegate method not called if i call this function from anywhere else then the delegate methods are called

Comment: sorry i didnt get you, so when are the delegate methods are called ?

Comment: when i call function from any other block.Actually here in my app i am accessing user contacts book so first time it asks for the permission for when user grant the permission a set of block is executed in that block i am  calling the function.Please check my complete code @T_77

Comment: i understood that,but you said delegate methods are executed in one case. So what is it?

Comment: I told you when i call it from any other block like it is called in viewdidLoad or any other block@T_77

Comment: This code works fine ! No problem in it. Even the delegates are also fired.

Comment: It does not works fine@Vizllx

Comment: delegate is not called if i call this function from AddressBook block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use like this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self sample];
});
```